# iPhone count number of shakes

Tags: iphone, ios

We want to count number of shakes done by user.

We tried motionBegan, motionEnded but its of no use.

Because they are fired only when user start a shake or ends a shake but i want to count shakes continuously.

May be something like this, when user moves iPhone to left one side and right one side, I count it as one shake.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: using NSNotification will help in any way?
i.e. when motion began i will send a notification and in that method, i will increase shake count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `UIAccelerometer` to achieve what you want.

You use motionBegin to detect a start :

```
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  UIAccelerometer* acc = [UIAccelorometer sharedAccelerometer];
  acc.delegate = self;
  acc.updateInterval = /* whatever you feel like OK */ 0.1;
}

- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  UIAccelerometer* acc = [UIAccelorometer sharedAccelerometer];
  acc.delegate = nil;
}
```

and in the delegate method :

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
  //
  // You detect a full shake
  //
}
```

**Before implementing this, you should know that UIAccelerometer has been deprecated in iOS5**. This means you will have to use what Apple recommands to use instead. I'm not updated yet on the topic.
Here is the documentation about it : [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks for solution but when i shake once, its counting as 5-6 times and if i shake for 4-5seconds and stop shaking.... shake count is increasing continously

PS. i am using an integer called shake `int shake` and in delegate and incrementing its value and NSLog its value there

how to fix it please